# Conda cannot be found in Git Bash when initialized and it only starts working if VSCode is restarted (VSCode on Windows)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, terminal, conda, git-bash

I use Windows 10, Conda, VSCode, and Git Bash terminal in VSCode.

**In short:**
When I start Git Bash in VSCode, `conda` does not work. When I restart VSCode, `conda` starts working as expected in the same terminal window. How to make `conda` work correctly in both situations?

**Detailed explanation:**

When I start Git Bash in VSCode for the first time (I will refer to this situation as "Initial"), the following output and error are generated:

```bash
source C:/Users/user/anaconda3/Scripts/activate base
bash: /cygdrive/c/Users/user/anaconda3/Scripts/conda.exe: No such file or directory
```

When I type `conda`, the following output appears:

```bash
conda
bash: /cygdrive/c/Users/user/anaconda3/Scripts/conda.exe: No such file or directory
```

When I restart VSCode and use the same terminal (I will refer to this situation as "After restart"), command `conda` works as expected. It is highly inconvenient to restart VSCode to make the terminal work correctly.

To debug:

1. I made sure that `conda` is on the PATH.
2. I checked other terminals (Command Prompt, PowerShell) and this issue was not present.
3. I checked Git Bash outside VSCode and the issue was not present.
4. Uninstalled and re-installed the whole Conda. It did not help.
5. I checked bash setup files: the file `~/.bashrc` does not exist and the contents of `~/.bash_profile` are:

```bash
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
if [ -f '/c/Users/user/anaconda3/Scripts/conda.exe' ]; then
    eval "$('/c/Users/user/anaconda3/Scripts/conda.exe' 'shell.bash' 'hook')"
fi
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

6. Checked environment variables via the `set` command.
   There were 3 different values of the environment variables returned by `set` in the Initial and After-restart Git Bash terminals:

```bash
# Initial:
CONDA_EXE=/cygdrive/c/Users/user/anaconda3/Scripts/conda.exe
# After restart:
CONDA_EXE=/c/Users/user/anaconda3/Scripts/conda.exe
```

```bash
# Initial:
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/cygdrive/c/Users/user/anaconda3/python.exe
# After restart:
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/c/Users/user/anaconda3/python.exe
```

```bash
# Initial:
_CONDA_ROOT='C:\Users\user\anaconda3'
# After restart
# (not present)
```

7. The contents of `C:/Users/user/anaconda3/Scripts/activate`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
_CONDA_ROOT="C:\Users\user\anaconda3"
# Copyright (C) 2012 Anaconda, Inc
# SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause
\. "$_CONDA_ROOT/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" || return $?
conda activate "$@"
```

8. The top rows of `~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`:

```bash
export CONDA_EXE="$(cygpath 'C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe')"
export _CE_M=''
export _CE_CONDA=''
export CONDA_PYTHON_EXE="$(cygpath 'C:\Users\user\anaconda3\python.exe')"
```

**Questions:**

1. Where does this `/cygdrive` come from?
2. What is the location of the Git Bash initialization code in VSCode?
3. Why do the values of `CONDA_EXE` and `CONDA_PYTHON_EXE` differ in the same terminal but in different circumstances (Initial and After restart)?
4. Why is this issue only present in Git Bash of VSCode, but neither in other terminals (Command Prompt, PowerShell) nor in Git Bash outside VSCode?
5. **How to fix the issue and make `conda` work in the Initial Git Bash terminal in VSCode?**
6. If the previous questions cannot be answered yet or some information is still missing, how should I debug further?

Comment: Have you run `conda init bash` in Git Bash? Also, use `conda activate`; the `source activate` scripts were superseded by `conda activate`.

Comment: Yes, I tried `conda init bash` in the terminal after a VSCode restart. When I ran it last time, the comment was `no change` for all listed files. In the initial (new) terminal, the code `source C:/Users/user/anaconda3/Scripts/activate base` is autogenerated by VSCode. I do not know how to change it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch at first Git Bash *in* VSCode...maybe that needs to configure to use login mode? I know plain VSCode terminal needs to have the shell configured to use `bash -l` in order to activate Conda environments. But I also am not on Windows, so not sure if that transfers.